# why does my rest API gets invalid characters?

Tags: php, rest, file-get-contents

Since some days, my service can't use information it obtains by my API
The JSON is well formed, but when the string is received by file_get_contents, it adds some character in front of the string.
I finished by find that these invalid characters are ascii 239,187,191
Why does it change that? What can I do to avoid this problem?

The server is an ugly windows server, i think that this horror comes from here, but not sure, I don't own it.
The API is on codeigniter, not made by myself, and the client is on my own framework.

If I search in the response with this code:

```
    $test = file_get_contents($test);
    for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($test); $i++)
    {
        echo $i;
        echo " : ";
        echo $test[$i];
        echo " / ";
        echo ord($test[$i]);
        echo "<br>";
    }


    die;
```

I have this result:
0 : � / 239
1 : � / 187
2 : � / 191
3 : c / 99
4 : b / 98
5 : s / 115
6 : a / 97
7 : $ / 36
8 : 5 / 53
9 : c / 99
10 : 2 / 50
11 : 3 / 51

API side:

```
public function listeDossiers($token, $year, $month)
{
    $token=$this->hexToStr($token);

    $token = substr($token,3);
    $connexion = $this->ConnLabo_model->findByToken($token);

    if($connexion !== null){
        header('content-type:application/json');
        $liste = json_encode($this->RendezVous_model->findByLabo($connexion->id_user, $year, $month) );
        echo $liste;
        return;
    }


}
```

Client side

```
    $this->view->setTpl('Liste');
    $this->layout->year=$year;
    $this->layout->month=$month;
    $file = $this->restConfig['server'] . "/listeDossiers/" . $this->strToHex(trim($_SESSION['token'])) . '/' . $year . '/' . $month;
    //var_dump($file);die;
    $file = file_get_contents($this->restConfig['server'] . "/listeDossiers/" . $this->strToHex(trim($_SESSION['token'])) . '/' . $year . '/' . $month ) ;
    $this->view->liste = json_decode( $file);
```

Comment: ASCII only contains values from 0 to 127. The characters you are getting (`EF BB BF` in hexadecimal) are the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of a UTF-8 stream.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but might be this issue is due to **charset** try to use

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

in your file.

Comment: I've already tried that, but nothing.
The author of the code thinks that's a buffer's problem, we will see

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, it was a file who had a bad charset (UTF8 with BOM), I converted that file and it's allright now.

Thanks for the help